# How to write/update a JSON file [UI5]

Tags: javascript, sapui5

`SAPUI5` provides you a way to load data from a `JSON`-file:

```
var oProductModel = new JSONModel();
oProductModel.loadData("./model/Products.json");
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oProductModel, "products");
```

**Question**: Is there an analog method to `.update` the `JSON`-file ?

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/96804e3315ff440aa0a50fd290805116#loio96804e3315ff440aa0a50fd290805116) states:

> The JSON model is a client-side model and, therefore, intended for small data sets, which are completely available on the client. [...]  **client-side models** like the JSON model **have no built-in support for sending data back to the server**.